# Build project error: cannot find symbol

Tags: java

I am getting these two errors. 
Error: Could not find or load main class Dice
Build project error: cannot find symbol

My file is saved as Dice.java. I checked because that was one of my problems with my last program. As far as the symbol error I am not sure.

public class Dice{  <---class is Dice

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

// Welcome message.
    System.out.println ("Welcome to The Dice Roller Game!");
```

// Roll the dice.

```
        int die1, die2;
        int rollcount;
        rollcount = 0;
    int wins = 0;
```

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);  <----line 13 symbol error

This is just a portion of the source code.

Comment: Which symbol cannot be found?

Comment: Have you made sure you've imported Scanner?

Comment: import java.util.Scanner; If you have forgot import Scanner class!

Comment: I put in the import java.util.Scanner; but it is still saying cannot find or load main class Dice.

Comment: Can you post the entirely error?

Comment: --------------------Configuration: Dice - JDK version 1.7.0_07 <Default> - <Default>--------------------
Error: Could not find or load main class Dice

Process completed.

Comment: Got it. typed it in the wrong area. Thanks sgmart!

Comment: I do not read books - I write them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classes that are not in the `java.lang` package must be imported to be used:

```
package com.foo.bar;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Dice {
    ...
```

Read more about packages and imports in [the Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am still very new to java so I am still trying to figure out all the terms.